# unity c#, unable to acces a variable form another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I would like to acces a variable called cooldown from another script called BulletScript and i cant figure out what's wrong with my codes.
Here are my codes:
1st:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class gunMechanic : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BulletScript bulletScript;

    private void Awake() {
        bulletScript = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<BulletScript>();
        Debug.Log(bulletScript.cooldown);
    }
}
```

2nd:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float cooldown = 1;
}
```

Comment: `bulletScript = FindObjectOfType<BulletScript>();` Try this

Comment: @Jaimin still not working

Comment: @Valentino: Please provide information to which gameObject these scripts are attached? How they are related to each other in the hierarchy? Some information will really help us to help you in a good way. If both these are on the same gameObject, then you simply have to use `GetComponent < BulletScript > ()` and it will work.

Comment: @nIcEcOw you are right, i forget that one of the scripts wasnt decalre yet and that cause the trouble, thanks for your help

Comment: @Valentino: Glad you found the answer. For the REST, YOU'RE MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are lots of different possible reasons for your issue. Try adding [[SerializeField]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) before `private BulletScript bulletScript;` and directly serialize object with your script.

It's possible that you:

1. don't add this script to object on your scene;
2. has those scripts in two different additively loaded scenes;
3. instancing object with second script after `Awake()` and/or `Start()`;
4. forget to instantiate object with the second script.

If you can provide any logs or more information about your project startup.

Comment: And my suggestion it's to avoid static variables in your project because later on, you will have lots of performance problems and bugs due to accessing this variable from different classes.

Comment: i tried to add [SerializeField] before it but i cant move my script there in unity

Comment: If you inherited the script from MonoBehaviour, you need to put this script on any GameObject in scene to use reference to it.

Comment: you are right, i forget that one of the scripts wasnt decalre yet and that cause the trouble, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you should declare the variable as `static`, if you want the value to be that of the script you are looking for it in.

Don't declare the class and then look for the variable, call it directly with `BulletScript.cooldown`